# JQUERY get list of checkboxes that are checked by ID

Tags: jquery

I currently have a list of checkboxes all with the same ID which are hidden and I want to grab the list of the ones that are checked, is this possible? I am currently using this format:

```
selected_list = $("#ID").attr("checked", "true");
```

this however is only returning the top one when I read them into a variable with a loop like this:

```
list = '';
$(selected_list).each(
    function() {
          list += $(this).val() + " ";
    } 
);

alert(list);
```

Anyone know of a better way of doing this or why my version is only returning the first checkbox? Thanks

Comment: How would you identify them if they have the same ID? They can all have the same class, but should have different IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't re-use ID values, they are supposed to be unique:

```
$("#elementID:checked");
```

Ideally, you should give them all the same class, or name, depending on how you want to use them. But you should never use the same ID over and over on a single page.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Apples"  class="fruit" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Oranges" class="fruit" />
```

We can select these various different ways. First, by class:

```
$(".fruit:checked");
```

Or simply by a vague checkbox call:

```
$(":checkbox:checked");
```

Or, in the case with radio buttons, if they all shared the same `name` value:

```
$("[name='elements']:checked");
```

Comment: what is a better way then? should I have them all have the same class name and then check by class?

Comment: @jquery_check I've updated my answer with a slighter more verbose explanation.

Comment: thanks, appreciate the help I have it working with class names now. Thanks again